# Change 'jar' file in Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, upgrade, liquibase

I am using liquibase-runner plugin in Jenkins which in turn uses liquibase3.5.1.

For my project requirements, I need to use liquibase3.5.3 through liquibase-runner. Is it possible to change liquibase jar in 'WEB-INF/lib' folder for liquibase-runner plugin? Do I need to do something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to either submit a pull request to https://github.com/jenkinsci/liquibase-runner-plugin or to fork that and build it yourself.